# What URL does a homescreen shortcut contain?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, developer-options, hyperlinks, developer-preview, microsoft-onenote

I want to make shortcuts to OneNote notes on android in a certain folder (not app launcher folders, but folders visible in a file manager app). To do so I want to create a `.url` file containig the link to the note. Unfortunately, it is [not possible to share notes](https://www.reddit.com/r/OneNote/comments/x2xxht/android_share_pagenotebook/) with OneNote, thus I have no idea how the links look like.

I was given the idea to [enable developer mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) on my android device and then to check the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#ui-overview) while tapping the Android home screen shortcut. This should reveal the full Intent which contains the link of the note. I tried to do so but I don't understand the android developer mode.

**Is this a possible way to find out the link of a shortcut of the home screen? Can anyone who succeeds in this share a OneNote home screen shortcut link**? I would like to know the link format so that I can make those shortcut link files by myself.

---

**What I mean by "link format"**: For example, I figured out that simply adding `?si=` at the end of a Spotify web link opens the app. Compare `https://open.spotify.com/track/3Bp8X5z1jgq7HS0tCr0liJ` which opens the song in browser to `https://open.spotify.com/track/3Bp8X5z1jgq7HS0tCr0liJ?si=` which opens the same song in the app. I hope there is a simple solution as this for OneNote: Once I know the differences in format I can easily make android shortcuts from web links.

Comment: I don't think you'd have success with OneNote's note shortcuts. They are [dynamic app shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts). They are managed by system itself. The shortcut info is shared with the default launcher app which only knows shortcut id. Even with shortcut id, a user using ADB (am start) cannot do a thing. I tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: Here's what I tried: `am start-activity -n com.microsoft.office.onenote/.ui.ONMSplashActivity -c com.android.launcher3.DEEP_SHORTCUT --es shortcut_id pageLocalId` where pageLocalId differs for each shortcut. For a demo note it looked like this: `am start-activity -n com.microsoft.office.onenote/.ui.ONMSplashActivity -c com.android.launcher3.DEEP_SHORTCUT --es 'shortcut_id' '{77A73696-E1EA-644B-9ECE-AEC247F25549}{1}'`. Nevertheless, I didn't get anywhere with this.

Comment: @Firelord Is this here of some help in this situation: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231799/create-a-widget-shortcut-to-an-app-url/233199#233199 ?

Comment: No. The answer is not relevant. // You could ask at [so] "how to correctly launch an intent that has shortcut id of a dynamic shortcut".

Comment: Links formatted like `onenote:https://[linktonote] will open in the OneNote app if clicked. I was able to create a link and follow it both via clicking in a document and with a Task top open it (created with Tasker) linked to a home screen widget. I don't know how these would be selectable via a file manager app though. Unfortunately, you can't generate these links from within the Android app it seems, I had to right-click a note in the Desktop app and select "copy link to page," then get that to my phone.

Comment: @jlehenbauer This sounds amazing! Unfortunately, this is not the case for me.. I made another question about that issue. Maybe you can have a look? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/251524/how-to-change-what-links-open-a-specific-app Thanks!