# How to open certain pages/ sections with OneNote app (not with browser) on android?

Tags: settings, hyperlinks, microsoft-onenote

I want to have links that open certain OneNote notes. I was told in comments of a [former question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/251522/what-url-does-a-homescreen-shortcut-contain?noredirect=1#comment339710_251522) that we can achieve this like that:

- Open OneNote on Windows, rightclick the note tab and choose "Copy Link of this note"
- This gives two links, of of them beein like this: `onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...`
- Clicking on this link on an android device should open the same note page with the OneNote app

Unfortunately, this is not the case for me! Here is the screenshot of how a Desktop-generated OneNote-link looks on my android phone:

[image: link on phone]

If I click on it the browser opens, not the app. In fact I am not too surprised because the beginging of the link, i.e. `onenote:`, is apperently not part of the link.

Further, I noticed that under `Settings -> Apps -> Apps -> OneNote -> Opening standards` only the following formats are listed under `supported links`: `*.sharepoint-df.com`, `onenoteresume.page.link`, `*.sharepoint.de` and `*.sharepoint.com`. So the suggested link format `onenote:https://[linktonote]` is not listed here. Can I somehow add it here? And: is the beginging `onenote:` important at all since it is not recognized as part of the link? I don't understand why the link does not open the app for me but does for others.

Comment: Yeah, the hard part is using this link through a service that will format it correctly. For instance, try pasting that link into a OneNote page itself and making that text it's hyperlink address. Then clicking it should take you to that other note.

A lot of services like Gmail, Messaging apps, etc. refuse to use anything preceeding "https://", invalidating the functionality of these links

Comment: @jlehenbauer What apps do you use that recognise the whole part being a link? Besides OneNote

Comment: It's hard to know what all works without trying each option individually. I was able to confirm that the "Browse URL" Task in Tasker will open these notes directly through the OneNote app.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out how to do this.. Step by step instruction how to create a `.url` file which opens OneNote app on android at the page you want.

- Open OneNote app on windows, go to the section or page you want to have a `.url` for.
- Rightclick on the tab opens menu, choose "Copy link for page"
- Open some text app like Word and paste. You get two links, one stars with `https://onedrive.live.com/...` and the other with `onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...`. Copy the `onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...` link.
- Create a new shortcut file by right-click in some folder or on desktop. In the first windows paste the link (including `onenote:...`), click next, then type in some name.
- Clicking on this shortcut should open the correct note page/ section in OneNote app on Windows.
- Share the file with your android device (if your email client forbids sharing `.url` files try uploading the file in a cloud).
- Download the file from cloud to mobile phone (opening from cloud caused error for me).
- Install the app [Open Any URL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.connectingsoftware.cbopenanyurl&hl=en).
- Click on the downloaded `.url` file, choose to open with Open Any URL and it will directly open the linked page with the OneNote app!

If you use a cloud to fodler client like FolderSync, this approach helps you because you can access the same notes by opening the same `.url` file on windows and android.